# gremlin console - can not connect using cassandra config

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph

I installed janus server (0.4) and cassandra (3.11) on my machine. They start correctly.

When I start the janus client to operate from the console

I run

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

the connection is successful

then if I use this command

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open ('conf/janusgraph-cassandra.properties')
```

I get the following error message

```
WARN org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager - Cassandra Thrift protocol is deprecated and will be removed with JanusGraph 0.5.0. Please switch to the CQL backend.
Could not open global configuration
```

The warning is clear while the error that it cannot load the global configuration does not.

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing the configuration file in question I noticed the following property:

```
storage.backend
```

This property sets the driver. By changing its value from:

```
cassandrathrift
```

to

```
CQL
```

everything works fine.

The warning should be an error if you need to use cql as a driver.

Instead, the message suggests that it is looking for a default configuration file.

It could be that, when using cassandrathrift as driver, some properties are not set and therefore look for their default value. At the moment I don't know in which path this default file should exist and how it should be done. Considering that the cassandrathrift driver is deprecated, I think it is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the same `conf/` dir as the Thrift-based config file, you should also see a `janusgraph-cql.properties` file.

This file should already have `storage.backend=cql` set, as well as a few other parameters allowing you to connect to a local Cassandra instance running on 127.0.0.1 (without security enabled).

Comment: Yes, I change my configuration file,janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties, by looking at janusgraph-cql.properties. I add elastic search to the stack. Tha main problem is that Thrift's driver not working.